# SKLearn Stacking Classifier giving bad results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am making a hybrid ensemble model with scikit learn. I tried to use stacking classfier to ensemble models where I used random forest, SVM and naive bayes with Logistic regression as meta estimator. I am using the heart disease dataset on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci) . The problem is that the solo techniques are performing better than the hybrid results. My hybrid model is using techniques with gridsearchCV of 5 fold validation and other best parameters. Whilst my solo techniques to which I am comparing model to , have default parameters. What I am doing wrong.

Logistic Regression :

```
C = [0.01,0.1, 1, 5, 10]

Log = LogisticRegression()

parameters = {'C': [.1 ,2, 5, 10, 15, 20]}

log_regressor = GridSearchCV(Log, parameters,cv =5)
log_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
log_regressor.best_params_
log_regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)
accuracy89 = log_regressor.score(X_test,y_test)

print('Logistic Regression Accuracy -->',((accuracy89)*100))
```

Naive bayes:

```
params_NB = {'var_smoothing': np.logspace(0,-9, num=100)}
NB = GaussianNB()
nb_regressor = GridSearchCV(NB, params_NB,n_jobs = -1 ,cv =5)
nb_regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)
accuracy76 = nb_regressor.score(X_test,y_test)
print('Naive Bayes Accuracy -->',((accuracy76)*100))
nb_regressor.best_params_
```

Similarly , SVC and Random forest were trained. Then the best parameter model was used here in stacking classifier:

```
estimators = [
    ('knn',model3_grid),
    ('svc',svm_regressor),
    ('nb',nb_regressor),
    ('rf',rf_classifier),
]

stackingCLF = StackingClassifier(estimators = estimators, verbose = 2 ,final_estimator = log_regressor, cv=5)
stackingCLF.fit(X_train, y_train)
StackedScore = stackingCLF.score(X_test, y_test)*100
print(StackedScore)
```

It is giving me 85 % accuracy but the solo tech. results are:

```
'DT': 0.7166666666666667,
 'KNN': 0.7833333333333333,
 'Logistic Regression': 0.8666666666666667,
 'NB': 0.5,
 'RF': 0.8166666666666667,
 'SVC': 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no guarantee that an ensemble can outperform all of its components.
2. Poorly performing base models may hurt the performance of the ensemble: although the meta-estimator can assign little weight to predictions of bad base models, it might get lead astray by some noise.  Try the same but without the NB and maybe the DT model.
3. Accuracy isn't a particularly good metric, and your test size is relatively small, so the difference between 0.85 and 0.8667 may not be significant.
4. You mention a difference in hyperparameter tuning; be sure you're including the default hyperparameters in the search space(s).

Comment: ok , then how can I build a hybrid model which works better than other any solo techniques. All I see everywhere is stacking and bagging or voting!! Is there any way I can build that? As I see various research papers mentioning Hybrid ML models, but I can't get anywhere on Internet how to make them except these mentioned tehnniques!

Comment: I am just asking for an alternative approach. I think it's acceptable

Comment: @GautamGoyal I did not say that it is not acceptable, I said that it is a whole *different* question from the original one. And why you are posting from [two different accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69777644/making-of-hybrid-machine-learning-model)?